# Google Fonts Spacing/Rendering Issue

Tags: html, css, google-webfonts

I am currently using [Josefin Slab](http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Josefin+Slab&subset=latin) from [Google Web Fonts API](http://www.google.com/webfonts) and having some rendeding / spacing issues.  I have tried everything to get the vertical alignment to match up from Firefox OSX to PC and cannot get them to render correctly.  Does anyone have experience with this that can lend some insight, I would like to continue to use the fonts for the navigation but may have to move to images for cross browser consistency.

Does anyone have any pointers of similar issues they may have experienced and addressed?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot and show your css code?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a possible workaround for you.

Webfont is tricky even Google can't get it right, it is mostly due to the fact each platform interpert the same font file differently. If you know scripting, you could detect OS, add className and adjust the style for each platform. [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) could do the same thing.